# Как можно оптимизировать код при решении задачи, угадай число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. Пытаюсь решить задачу угадай число. Подскажите, можно ли улучшить код в задаче угадай число, в частности в блоке if. Я только начал изучать Pytnon.

```
number = 37
count = 0
while count < 5:
    your_num = int(input('Введите число от 1 до 100: '))
    count += 1
    if your_num == number:
        if count == 1:
            print(f'Вы угадали число за {count} попытку. Спасибо за игру!')
        if 1 < count < 5:
            print(f'Вы угадали число за {count} попытки. Спасибо за игру!')
        if count == 5:
            print(f'Вы угадали число за {count} попыток. Спасибо за игру!')    
        break
    elif your_num < number:
        print('Ваше число меньше загаданного числа, попробуйте ещё раз.')
    elif your_num > number:
        print('Ваше число больше загаданного числа, попробуйте ещё раз.')
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Конечно можно, в моей реализации я бы использовал следующую конструкцию

```
import random


ATTEMPTS_COUNT = 5  # Количество попыток

MIN_GUESS_NUMBER = 1    # Минимально возможное число
MAX_GUESS_NUMBER = 100  # Максимально возможное число

GUESS_NUMBER = random.randrange(MIN_GUESS_NUMBER, MAX_GUESS_NUMBER) # Загадываем число

for attempt in range(ATTEMPTS_COUNT):
    number = int(input(f'Введите число от {MIN_GUESS_NUMBER} до {MAX_GUESS_NUMBER}: '))
    
    if number < GUESS_NUMBER:
        print('Ваше число меньше загаданного числа, попробуйте ещё раз.')
    elif number > GUESS_NUMBER:
        print('Ваше число больше загаданного числа, попробуйте ещё раз.')
    elif number == GUESS_NUMBER:
        print(f'Вы угадали число за {attempt + 1} попыт(ку/ок), спасибо за игру!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли улучшить код в задаче угадай число, в частности в блоке if

вы можете переписать блок `if` примерно так (это короче, но не уверен, что лучше):

```
number = 37
count = 0
while count < 5:
    your_num = int(input('Введите число от 1 до 100: '))
    count += 1
    if your_num == number:
        print(f"Вы угадали число за {count} попыт{['ку','ки','ки','ки','ок'][count-1]}. Спасибо за игру!")
        break
    print(f"Ваше число {['меньше','больше'][your_num>number]} загаданного числа, попробуйте ещё раз." if count < 5 else 
          f'Вы не угадали. Загаданное число - {number}.')
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.